# Identifying sentence error

Tags: errors

> M.J. Hyland, who authored the acclaimed 2003 novel *How the Light Gets
>   In,* is often praised **to be a subtle** and complex portrayer of
>   human psychology.

What is wrong with the bolded construction and why? My gut bet would be that it should be replaced with 'praised as' but I want to be sure of the grammatical reason why this is incorrect.

Comment: Homework doesn't work if you don't try to answer it yourself. What do you think is wrong with the phrase? Why?

Comment: Does praising the novel make it a subtle and complex portrayer of human psychology?

Comment: @DanBron It's not a homework question but a real SAT test question. That part was marked incorrect. My gut bet would be that it should be replaced with 'praised as' but I want to be sure of the grammatical reason why this is incorrect.

Comment: Perhaps "for being" instead of "to be".

Comment: The simple answer here is that, idiomatically, English permits "Hyland is praised as a subtle and complex portrayer" and "Hyland is praised for being a subtle and complex portrayer," but not "Hyland is praised to be a subtle and complex portrayer." As aparente001 observes in an answer below, usage of the verb _praise_ determines correctness—and "praised to be" fails on that measure.

Answer (score 0):

OR: often praised for being ....

The type of error in your SAT practice test sentence is in the realm of *usage*.